# Is bower auto-updating itself from github?

Tags: bower

From the documentation it is not clear to me how to update the packages by Bower when I increase the version number. By npm you have to run npm publish. Does bower auto-updates the stored packages from github after I registered the package, or how does this work?

Should I add only the browser specific builds to the bower.json and let nodejs ppl install my lib from npm? (currently only nodejs is supported by my lib, but I intend to support browsers with browserify later.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bower does automatically keep up with your package updates, as long as you tag your releases and push the tags:

```
git commit -am "new version"
git tag -a v1.0.1 -m "1.0.1"
git push origin master --tags
```

More specification in the docs would be nice. [**This**](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register) is the best hint that I can find:

> Your package must be publically available at a Git endpoint (e.g.,
>   GitHub). Remember to push your Git tags!

Comment: It's simple with WebStorm: `VCS / Git / tag...` you add a new tag with the semver name and a message. After that you have to check the push tags checkbox by pushing the commits. That's all.